# How can I reach dynamic routes when using @vite-pwa/nuxt

Tags: progressive-web-apps, nuxt3, dynamic-routing

I'm using Nuxt 3.7.0.
My directory structure is:

```
-pages
    -pubs
        [id].vue
```

When I go to /pubs/somepub the page is displayed correctly.
I then install @vite-pwa/nuxt and configure the module in nuxt.config.ts using:

```
pwa: {
    manifest: {...name etc},
    workbox: {
      navigateFallback: '/'
    }
}
```

Then if I go to /pubs/somepub, I get routed to the root page. I have tried adding

```
globIgnores: [/pubs/]
```

to the workbox and

```
navigateFallbackDenylist: [/^\/pubs/]
```

But I still can't access my dynamic routes. What do I need to do to get this to work correctly?